# How to set W10 to keep the LAN connection always awake, even when laptop is sleeping?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

**Short Question :**

Is there a way i can tell W10 to keep the LAN connection always awake, even when laptop is sleeping ?

---

**Longer Question with Background :**

Ive got a Dell laptop, running W10 Pro, which connects to the network over wifi, i keep the laptop plugged into the mains power supply, most of the time (although its a laptop, i use with more as a Desktop with external displays etc, and only move it pretty infrequently)

On my router ive setup a Mac -> IP binding for the laptop.

Im trying to remote into the laptop using Microsoft Remote Desktop (MRD) but when the Dell laptop goes to sleep it seems to close its network connection, so i can no longer find it on a LAN scan, nor connect to it using MRD.

Is there a way i can tell the laptop to keep the LAN connection always awake ?

Comment: When a PC goes into sleep mode it shuts down the CPU and hence disconnects from network that is the normal way. If you want to wake-up the notebook from sleep you can only disable sleep mode or try to send a Wake-On-LAN magic wake-up packet - but AFAIR this usually works only via LAN, not Wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are some steps that could help.

**Set the network adapter to never sleep**

- Run the Device Manager
- Open the section Network adapters
- Right-click the adapter and select Properties
- In the Power Management section, uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
- Click OK

**Set the computer to never sleep**

- Run Power Option
- Click Change plan settings
- In the Plugged in section, set "Turn off the display" to your preference
  and "Put the computer to sleep" to Never

This will turn off the display to conserve power and monitor lifetime,
but keep the computer on

**Set the router to Wake-on-LAN**

An alternative to never sleep is to be able to wake up the computer when required.

[Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)
requires the hardware to be able to send the wake package,
and especially the router.

See the following posts:

- [RDP wake-on-lan in LAN environment](https://superuser.com/a/700246/8672)
- [Wake-on-lan only works so many times](https://superuser.com/a/242943/8672)